# Join 2 tables in mongodb with rails

Tags: mongodb, join, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

How can I perform a join operation on 2 tables while working in rails?
Give a simple solution to perform search on joining 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store copies of data in multiple tables/collections. In doing so, you avoid the need for JOINs and lookups needed to stitch together related pieces of data.

You avoid joins and you’re storing more data.

In mongoid there are two great gems to make this easier:

Mongoid_alize & Mongoid_denomalize

http://blog.joshdzielak.com/blog/2012/05/03/releasing-mongoid-alize-comprehensive-field-denormalization-for-mongoid/

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not have tables. MongoDB does not have schema. For those and other reasons, MongoDB does not support joins.

You have to make two queries: one for the element on Collection A, and another one on Collection B (using the reference obtained in first query).

You can take a look to [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does now support joins as of 3.2: [MongoDB Blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction)

Mongoid does not seem to be supporting it yet.